# How to redirect to the error page when exception has been caught in the controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

In jQuery I have the following function:

```
function submitInventoryModal(unitFinancialCalendarId) {
    const invoiceForm = $('form#submittalForm');
    const formData = invoiceForm.serialize();
    $.post('/Inventory/SaveInventorySubmittal', formData)
        .success(function (response) {
            debugger;
            console.log(response);
            viewSubmitConfirmation(unitFinancialCalendarId);
            removeNavigationModalRequirement();
        });
}
```

In `SaveInventorySubmittal` the code has been implemented as:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveInventorySubmittal(InventorySubmittalBE inventorySubmittal)
{
    try
    {
     
        RsiAsyncResult saveResult = await _inventoryService.SaveInventorySubmittalAsync(inventorySubmittal);
        if (!saveResult.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("Message", Strings.Home,
                new { Heading = "Error Saving Inventory Submittal", Message = "Invalid GL Configuration", SubMessage = saveResult.GetErrorString(), Icon = "user-times" });
        Logger.LogInformation($"Inventory Submittal with UnitInventorySubmittalId: {inventorySubmittal.UnitInventorySubmittalId} saved successfully.");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return RedirectToException(ex);
    }
}
```

In this above method `SaveInventorySubmittal`, an exception is thrown from the `_inventoryService`, but the catch blocks return the `RedirectToExceptiion`, which doesn't throw the exception and also is supposed to be redirected to the error page (Message view). But that doesn't happen.

The `RedirectToException` method is implemented as:

```
protected RedirectToActionResult RedirectToException(Exception exception)
{
    LogException(exception);

    // If it's an RSI Exception, display the message
    RsiException rsiException = exception as RsiException;

    if (rsiException != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Message", Strings.Home, new
        {
            Heading = "Error",
            Message = rsiException.DisplayMessage,
            SubMessage = ErrorSubMessage,
            Icon = "bomb"
        });
    }

    // For non-RSI exceptions, display something generic
    return RedirectToAction("Message", Strings.Home, new
    {
        Heading = "Error",
        Message = "We're sorry. An unexpected error has occurred.",
        SubMessage = ErrorSubMessage,
        Icon = "bomb"
    });

}
```

Due to this implementation, the redirects never happens from the `submitInventoryModal` in jQuery.

I wanted to redirect to the "Message" view, but the ajax code just goes into its own flow. How should I do the redirect?

Comment: Existing question that may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129694/what-happens-when-an-ajax-request-gets-a-302-moved-response

Comment: Another, more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not redirect at the Controller side as you are using AJAX.POST.
You will have to return JSON.

```
 catch(Exception ex)
  {
    LogException(ex);
   return Json(new { status="error",message="error in details"});
  }
```

Client-side:

```
  $.post('/Inventory/SaveInventorySubmittal', formData)
        .success(function (response) {
            debugger;
            console.log(response);
            viewSubmitConfirmation(unitFinancialCalendarId);
            removeNavigationModalRequirement();
            if(response.status=="error"){
              window.location.href = 'on error page'; 
            }
        })
```

Comment: exception may occurs from the multiple sources and you may need to use the same method on multiple instances, and returning that exception may not be a help.

Comment: Yes, else you will have to use the form POST method then your RedirectToAction will work.